# Crediting event payments by another contact

Tags: civievent

We fairly often have events where a registrant pays for part of their fee, and another contact (sometimes also a participant) pays the rest. I'd like to record the payment for the Contact and soft credit it to the appropriate participant's event fee.

Any chance this is possible? I'd be open to manipulating the database, if it's not possible in the civi interface.

Answer (score 2):

You could hack the civicrm_participant_payment table which links a contribution to a participant.
You could also create an extension to link a contribution to a particpant from the user interface. This way you make it easier for the event manager to this.

Comment: Thanks, Jaap. I'll look into it. I'm not really a programmer, just a dabbler, but I'd love a useful programming project to learn some more stuff with.